# Defining the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the weak topology of a pairing without talking about topology

Tags: measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces, borel-sets, weak-topology

Let $(X,Y,b)$ be a [pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak_and_strong_topologies), i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are real vector spaces and $b:X\times Y\to\mathbb R$ is bilinear. $\sigma(X,Y,b)$ is the weakest topology on $X$ such that $b(\cdot, y)$ is continuous for all $y\in Y$. Let $\Sigma$ be the Borel sigma algebra generated by $\sigma(X,Y,b)$.

Let $Z=\{ b(\cdot, y) :y\in Y \}$ and let $\Sigma'$ be the smalest $\sigma$-algebra such that all $z\in Z$ is measurable.

> Under what conditions is it true that $\Sigma=\Sigma'$ ?

---

It is quite clear that $\Sigma'\subseteq \Sigma$, indeed all element of $z$ are $\sigma(X,Y,b)$-continuous and therefore $\Sigma$-measurable.

I am a little worried about the other direction, indeed suppose we have an open set $A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal I} z_i^{-1}(B_i)$ where $\mathcal I$ is uncountable, $z_i\in Z$ and $B_i$ some non empty open intervals. Then it feels like because the union is uncountable, this may not be in $\Sigma'$.

> My goal is to try to define $\Sigma$ without appealing to topology in a document I am writing, I would like to avoid imposing a topological background on the people that might read it, hopefully it is doable in some way.

Any input on one of those two things would be most welcome.

---

An alternative definition without having to dwell too much into topology would be the following.

> For any $A\subseteq X\times Y$, let $U_A=\{ z\in X : \forall (x,y)\in A, b(x,y)\leq b(z,y) \}$. Then let $\mathcal F=\{ U_A : A\subseteq X\times Y \}$, it is not too hard to show that $\sigma(\mathcal F)=\Sigma$.

I think this could do for my purpose but anything simpler would be most welcome.